# 'std::bad_alloc' is thrown when trying to allocate a set of more than 10^8 integers

Tags: c++, memory, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am using `g++ 9.2.0` complier with a 16 GB memory, 64-bit pc,

when I was trying to allocate a large block of memory in my program, I met with this error:

```
c++ terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
```

A minimal example is below:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
const int MAX_N = 1000000;
struct {
    set<int> rels;
} arr[MAX_N];
int main() {
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_N; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 250; j++)
            arr[i].rels.insert(j);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I *do* know that 250,000,000 integers take a lot of space. But They're not expected to be larger than `250000000*32/8/1024/1024` = `954 MB`, which is **only one sixteenth** of my computer's physical memory.

Is there any way to make my program able to allocate a larger space, like 2 GB or more?

Comment: Are you compiling for 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: A `set` is a binary tree, so each entry in a `set` has a value, a left pointer and a right pointer. Since pointers are 64-bits, that's a minimum of 17 bytes per `set` entry, likely rounded up to 24 or 32. So this would likely require around 6GB to 10GB.

Comment: *which is only one sixteenth of my computer's physical memory.* -- All of that memory doesn't mean anything if your program is compiled as 32-bit.  Also it doesn't matter if your PC's operating system is 64-bit -- if you build a 32-bit program, it cannot access all of the memory you claim your PC has.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz oh I forgot that. However, the program died when using up only around 2 GB ram, rather than used up all of the free memory. It confuses me.

Comment: `const int MAX_N = 1000000; struct {  set<int> rels;} arr[MAX_N];` -- This does not use the heap.  This uses the stack memory, which is limited.  Why are you declaring arrays this size anyway?  This should cause an instant failure if run on a program with a default stack size of just a few megabytes.

Comment: @CodyGray yes, the complier is `mingw-w64`.

Comment: A 64-bit compiler can generate either 32-bit or 64-bit binaries. Which are you asking it to generate? What is your compiler command line?

Comment: _"...However, the program died when using up only around 2 GB ram..."_ leads me to believe this is a 32-bit build not a 64-bit build of the program. `mingw-w64` is a 64-bit compiler (not the target) it may or may-not default to building 64-bit programs.  You should check by passing the appropriate target architecture flags to the compiler.

Comment: @CodyGray the command line is `g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -O2 -m64  -c main.cpp -o main.o` and `g++.exe  -o main.exe main.o  -s -m64`.

Comment: @w568w -- Reduce that `MAX_N` number to 100.  Does your program run?  You also failed to mention at what iteration of the loop this occurs.  If the failure is immediate, then all signs point to that enormous stack-based array causing havoc.

Comment: @w568w The amount of RAM you have is almost completely irrelevant. What matters is the amount of backing store (RAM+swap) that the process is permitted to reserve or map.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the program works fine with `MAX_N <= 1e5`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I see, thanks for your explanation. I wonder there is any method to "enlarge" the space permitted, or other way to allocate and access such a big array? I've seen some programs on PC can easily take up nearly all the rest of physical memory.

Comment: @w568w, why do you need an array of set? What is the exact use case? Can't you use better data structures for your use case?

Comment: One simple optimization in the code in the post is to use `unsigned char` instead of `int`, since the inner for loop only iterates till 250. `unsigned char` can store up to 255. You reduce memory usage by approx. 4 times that way.

Comment: @kiner_shah thanks for advice. The minimal example above, however, is extracted from a complex mathematical simulation program, and it will be much slower if using other data structure rather than a `set<int>`.

Comment: @w568w -- *rather than a set<int>* -- Sorry, but I bet someone could come up with a faster method.  Second `std::unordered_set<int>` is probably faster.  Last, declaring giant arrays is in all honestly a very lazy way to write such a program.  It looks like one of those bad code examples you see from a competitive coding website, where the programmer is declaring giant arrays, just because the criteria states that `N can be up to 10-e6`.  Instead, a growable data structure, i.e. `std::vector<std::set>` would be used.

Comment: I've ran this on both of MSVCs 32 and 64 bit compilers; confirmed that on the 32-bit compiler it falls over when the overall memory usage hits 2GB.  On the 64-bit compiler it keeps chugging away past 3GB.

BTW `arr` is *not* on the stack; it's a global variable.